# How to use AWS CodeDeploy to ec2 nginx folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating an AWS CodeDepoly config. I have one ec2 instance and running nginx on it. I also have a 3s basket and it contains an artifact, a folder with site files (one index.html file), I want CodeDepoly to simply take it corny and copy it to a specific folder in this ec2 instance. How to do it? Can't CodeDepoly do such basic functionality? Where to specify the path in ec2 where to copy the folder with artifacts?

Comment: Off course it can. What is your `appspec.yml`? Did you program it?

Comment: "appspec.yml" oh =) Thank you! can you frame this as an answer? i will choose it as correct. It's just that the AWS console didn't say a word about this file, and I didn't even know that such a file needed to be created. Now I know what to google) thank you.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeDeploy only performs actions specified in [appspec.yml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html). Thus, if you want it to copy/change any files on your instance, you have to write the scripts to do it and reference them in `appspec.yml`.